# LVM or not for KVM storage?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, storage, lvm

Is there any issue with using LVM for your host server's storage pools or raw devices that are used by KVM guest? Eg. say I want to add storage to the /home directory on my KVM guest.  I have a Volume Group with 100Gb free. I create a 50Gb logical volume, and add it to the guest as /dev/vdb. Then I log into the guest, and add /dev/vdb to extend my volume group.

I just want to know if there's any problem with this. There's not too much documentation about this out there. I guess it seem like I'm putting a volume group on top of a volume group. I've been doing this for a while and haven't had any problems. In fact, it has been convenient in the case where I have a large volume group, and need to export multiple devices to multiple guests.

Thanks!

Comment: Its fine. Its generally easier for KVM guest systems to be installed with root on /dev/vdb rather than it being a LV/VG inside the KVM. It just saves a few steps in the resize (and a few remappings on read/write).

Answer (score 3):

LVM, as well as MDADM, is a good choice for virtualization and everything must be working just fine. Also, I've used multiple software RAID in Linux and for example, ZFS is the best choice for archival data or backups but not for virtualization.